# Python programming - math library that uses degrees by default

Tags: technology-in-education, trigonometry

Other than the standard math module for Python3, is there another library out there that uses degrees by default (as opposed to radians)? I am teaching students to use turtle (which uses degrees by default) to draw figures and they need to use trigonometry to compute angles/sides. Right now they are only familiar with degrees. Ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not really about mathematics education, but rather seeks a recommendation for a software package.  While I think that there is likely an on-topic question in here somewhere, the relevance to MESE is not clear in the current from.

Answer (score 6):

May I suggest giving them a bit of header code? i.e. Instead of using

```
from math import sin
```

try

```
import math

def sin(theta):
    return math.sin(math.radians(theta))
```

Comment: This is better than my answer, so I deleted mine. But it might be nicer to supply this to the students as a library rather than as a big block of code that they have to cut and paste.

Comment: My first thought was "any trig library that natively uses degrees rather than radians is  a sin". (In all seriousness, I get that it would be helpful to some, but under the hood, all implementations of trig functions will use radians. If one uses degrees, it's just doing the conversion for you.)

Comment: @jvriesem I suppose you could call the functions `sin_of_degrees()` and the like, which at least makes it explicit.